# got confused on deeplink in React navigation version 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Hi guy got stuck on structure deeplink in nested navigator first here my navigation code 
it's just stack inside tab

```
function HomeStack() {
return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
            name="SinglePost"
            component={SinglePost}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and bottomtabs

```
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
```

so this is config part of react navigation that for organize deeplink 
first i put a stack parent

```
const config = {
Home: {
    path: "stack",
    initialRouteName: "SinglePost",
    screens: {
        Home: "home",
        SinglePost: {
            path: "post/:post_id",
            parse: {
                post_id: Number,
            }
        }
    }
  }
};
```

then when navigate to this screen with

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted kriss://post/3232
```

here sresult 
[image]

thank for advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem lays in the current implementation of `getStateFromPath` function, which creates the navigation state from the given path. The regexp parsing the params after `:` looks like this: 
`const match = new RegExp('^' + escape(pattern).replace(/:[a-z0-9]+/gi, '([^/]+)') + '/?');` so it will correctly parse only alphanumeric params. It will be changed soon, for now please use e.g. `postId` instead of `post_id` and it should work just fine.